# Translate custom order status through a filter?

Tags: filters, translation, localization

I'm using this plugin to customize order statuses in Woocommerce: [Woocommerce Order Status Manager](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-order-status-manager/)

In documentation it says I translate order status name using the following filter:

```
wc_order_status_manager_order_status_name
```

Indeed, in plugin source there are these lines:

```
public function get_name() {

    /**
     * Filter the name
     *
     * @since 1.3.0
     * @param string $name The order status name
     * @param string $slug The order status slug
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wc_order_status_manager_order_status_name', $this->name, $this->slug );
}
```

In my theme's functions.php I added the following code:

```
function af_change_shipped_status_name($name, $slug){
if ('shipped' == $slug){
    $name = __('Shipped', 'mythemetextdomain');
}   
return $name;
}

add_filter( 'wc_order_status_manager_order_status_name', 'af_change_shipped_status_name', 10, 2 );
```

But it's not working.

Were am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Recheck your filter code closely. You are modifying `$name` but returning `$status_name` which is undefined. If you had debugging enabled, you should have seen the debug message telling you that `$status_name` is an undefined variable

Simply change

```
return $status_name;
```

to

```
return $name;
```

Comment: Hi Pieter, I'm sorry I mess up with variable names when inserting the code here in the question. Problem is that even returning the right variable, filter is still not working. PS: should I edit the question with the right variable or not?

Comment: Have you tried changing the priority of `10` to something like `11` or `999`, and are your values what you expect them to be. Do `var_dump($name)`and `var_dump($slug)` to check your values. If this does not help, file an edit with all updated info

Comment: I tried changing filter priority just like you suggested, but it's not translating. How to var_dump in a filter function?